# Problem involving Cauchy's inequality and inequality between quadratic and arithmetic means

Tags: inequality

I am working on a problem in an elementary mathematics book. I have come up with a solution, but it doesn't seem to work. At this point I'm thinking there may be an error in the book, but maybe I'm missing something.

The problem goes :
Let $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}$ be positive reals. Prove that :
\begin{equation}
\sum_{1 \le i < j < k \leq 4} \frac{a_{i}^{2} + a_{j}^{2} + a_{k}^{2}}{a_{i}+a_{j}+a_{k}} \geq a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + a_{4}
\end{equation}
with equality iff $a_{1} = a_{2} = a_{3} = a_{4}$.

I think we are supposed to use this inequality to derive the solution :
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{ \frac{a_{1}^{2} + a_{2}^{2} + \dots + a_{n}^{2}}{n} } \geq \frac{a_{1} + a_{2} + \dots + a_{n}}{n}
\end{equation}
I have derived that :
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\sqrt{ \frac{a_{i}^{2} + a_{j}^{2} + a_{k}^{2}}{3} } & \geq \frac{a_{i} + a_{j} + a_{k}}{3}\\
\sqrt{a_{i}^{2}+a_{j}^{2}+a_{k}^{2}} & \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}(a_{i}+a_{j}+a_{k})}{3} \\
a_{i}^{2} + a_{j}^{2} + a_{k}^{2} & \geq \frac{\cancel{3}(a_{i}+a_{j}+a_{k})^{2}}{\cancel{9}}\\
\frac{a_{i}^{2}+a_{j}^{2}+a_{k}^{2}}{(a_{i}+a_{j}+a_{k})} & \geq \frac{(a_{i}+a_{j}+a_{k})}{3}
\end{align}
So :
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{1}^{2} + a_{2}^{2} + a_{3}^{2}}{a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}} & \geq \frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}}{3} \\
\frac{a_{2}^{2}+a_{3}^{2}+a_{4}^{2}}{a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}} & \geq \frac{a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}}{3} 
\end{align}
So :
\begin{equation}
\sum_{1\leq i < j < k \leq 4} \frac{a_{i}^{2}+a_{j}^{2}+a_{k}^{2}}{a_{i}+a_{j}+a_{k}} \geq \frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}}{3}
\end{equation}
But this doesn't prove the needed result. Can someone help with this ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that $1\leq i\lt j\lt k\leq 4$ contains not just $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,3,4)$

It contains $(1,2,4)$ and $(1,3,4)$ as well.

There are $\binom 43=4$ such tuples $(i,j,k)$ and indeed that gives you $$\geq\frac{\sum\limits_{1\leq i\lt j\lt k\leq 4}a_i+a_j+a_k}3\\ =\frac{(a_1+a_2+a_3)+(a_1+a_2+a_4)+(a_1+a_3+a_4)+(a_2+a_3+a_4)}3$$

which simplifies to $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$

In general, we have,

> $$\sum_{1\leq i_1\lt i_2\lt\dots\lt i_k\leq n}\sum_{m=1}^k a_{i_m}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}\sum_1^n a_i$$

which can be proven by a simple counting argument. Try it out!

Following which, here is a more general version of the inequality given in your problem:

> $$\sum_{1 \le i_1\lt i_2\lt\dots\lt i_k\leq n}\frac{\sum\limits_{m=1}^k a_{i_m}^2}{\sum\limits_{m=1}^k a_{i_m}} \geq \frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}k\sum_1^n a_i$$ with equality iff all $a_i$'s are equal.

which admits the same proof as yours.

The inequality in your question is the special case of the result above with $n=4$ and $k=3$